# Slow publishing in Azure umbraco website

Tags: azure, umbraco

I have an umbraco website setup in Azure. The front-end website loads fine but the back end takes more than 15 seconds from when you hit the "Save and Publish" to show the check mark denoting success. I setup a test website but in Azure VM pointing to the same Azure sql database that hosts the same umbraco Azure website and I don't get this problem.

Comment: Not exactly sure what your question is: This is about deployment time? Or something else? And where are you deploying to: Azure Web Apps? Please edit your question to include more details. But... even with more info, I'm not sure what, exactly, anyone can do to help: It's not a programming question, and unless you're providing logging info, I don't see how anyone can help speed up a deployment (assuming that's what the issue is). Possibly your Web App instance size? (assuming it's web app)

Comment: Sorry I was not more detailed. I have an umbraco website setup as IaaS web apps in Azure. The web pages load time is OK. In the umbraco back office, when I publish content, it takes between 15 - 20 secs to do. I have a setup in a VM and doing the same tasks takes 5 secs. I don't think it's the app size (The web apps is running on S2 and the sql azure is S1)

Answer (score 2):

I just spent some time debugging this same scenario. We had a situation where once someone saved a node, it would take 30 seconds before the UI would become responsive again. Network trace confirmed that we were waiting on API calls back from Umbraco.

We were on an S0 SQL instance, so I bumped it to S1 and the perf got worse!? (guessing indexes rebuilding?).

We already have a few Azure specific web.config options set (like useTempStorage="Sync" in our ExamineSettings.config). Ended up adding the line below and now our saves went from 30-35s to 1-2s!

```
<add key="umbracoContentXMLUseLocalTemp" value="true" />
```

This is from the load balancing guide available here - https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Server-Setup/load-balancing/flexible

Comment: Also this answer explain way it is like that : https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started//84291-azure-umbraco-after-publishing-old-page-the-site-is-down-for-2-mins.

"Any Azure Web App deployment should have this setting otherwise it will store umbraco.config in the insanely slow shared storage location, this setting moves it to the local temp but fast location"

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco Save and publish is fairly DB intensive. An S1 instance is possibly not beefy enough. We use S2 for our dev sites, and that can take up to 5 seconds to save and publish depending on whether anything else is hitting the database.

You may also have issues with other code running that's slowing things down. Things like Examine indexing can be quite slow on Azure. It could also be one a plugin that slowing things down.

How complex are your DocTypes? Also, which version of Umbraco are you running? Some older versions have bugs in that cause performance issues on Azure.